# Domain Name and DC in LDAP

Tags: active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I'm trying to connect Active Directory supporting LDAP with SSL.

But am confused with some terms. Help me to understand in very simple way.

Please correct me

1. `Domain Name or Host Name or DNS`: this is the server address or name where the Active Directory service is running.
2. `DC or Domain Component or Domain Controller`: this is a folder name within Active Directory. For example If I give `DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"`, then `gp` is folder inside `google` and `google` is inside `com` folder.
3. `CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups`: `CN` is a user name which belongs to `OU group`. And this user will look for something in  `DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com"` folder structure.
4. Can host name be similar to like top level DC (Folder) name?
5. What is the difference between DC and AD domain name and host name in LDAP?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. A domain name in general is an internet address that can be resolved through the Domain Name System (DNS), just like stackoverflow.com or example.com. Every Active Directory domain is a domain name just like that.
2. The acronym "DC" is usually used to refer to a "domain controller". A domain controller is a server, which is assigned the role of being an authority for that Active Directory domain. Every AD domain needs at least one DC, but it can have more than one.

2. (b) The format `DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com` is called a "distinguished name". In that context, DC stands for "domain component". `gp` is not a folder inside `google`. Each `DC` component of the distinguished name represents one "domain component" of the domain name. So that example would correspond to a domain called `gp.gl.google.com`. For a domain called `example.com`, the distinguished name would be `DC=example,DC=com`.
3. If you have a distinguished name of `CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com`, that correspond to an object called `Dev-India`. It could be a user, group, computer, contact, etc. You cannot tell what type of object it is just by the distinguished name. That `Dev-India` object is in the `Distribution Groups` organizational unit (OU) on the domain `gp.gl.google.com`.
4. The term "host name" is not often used with Active Directory. But in general, a "host name" is just the computer that is "hosting" the information you are looking for.
5. I think this was answered by the other questions already.

Here is some extra reading that might help:

- [Core Concepts of Active Directory Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/core-concepts-of-active-directory-domain-services)
- [User Naming Attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties)

Comment: @Gabreil Luci, then what's a purpose DCs ? And what defines a folder structure in Active directory ?

Comment: DCs run your Active Directory domain. You cannot have an AD domain without at least on DC.

Comment: You won't find the term "folder structure" used with AD, but I understand what you mean. Read this: [Containers and Leaves](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/containers-and-leaves)

Comment: To connect AD, I'm giving hostName, Port, username, passoword, SSL certificate and something like this CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution Groups,DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com.  Hostname, port and SSL certificate will be used just to connect with server where AD is installed ? Correct ? Then once its connected,  DC will match his name with DC=gp,DC=gl,DC=google,DC=com came from request. Once its matched, DC will check that whether user's credentials matches or not in this category   CN=Dev-India,OU=Distribution. If it matches, we are good to extract info. Makes sense ?

Comment: That sounds about right. Except the credentials can be any user on the domain or a trusted domain, as long as the permissions on the object you're reading haven't been changed to restrict who can read it.

Comment: DC in the context of DNS (and LDAP) is a domainComponent as defined RFC 4519 Section 2.4. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4519#section-2.4

Comment: @jwilleke Ah, ok. You learn something everyday. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: A small correction: DC stands for "Domain Component", not domain controller.